# Android SQLite wrapper keeps query open in CursorAdapter, is this good?

Tags: android, sqlite

**EDIT** the assumption of this question is wrong, Android doesn't keep the query open, but it can cause other problems. See discussion bellow...

---

The Android Cursor implementation keeps a scrolling window of the underlining SQLite cursor, so it can implement "move forwards".

But I found a old SQLite documentation saying this is a bad practice, and you should not leave query open for UI inputs:

https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Also for example Telegram use it's own wrapper of SQLite, and don't have the scrolling cursor. https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/SQLite/SQLiteCursor.java . They only have "next"

Also there is the "best practice" to call "getCount" in CursorLoader, if you look at the implementation, it actually tries to loop through all the data in the underlining query.

---

So is Android's wrapper implementation bad? Is SQLite doc outdated and it is ok to keep query open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Android Cursor implementation keeps a scrolling window of the
>   underlining SQLite cursor, so it can implement "move forwards".

Both scrollable and non-scrollable cursors implement `move forward`, i think you meant `move backward` here.

The documentation you specified, doesn't tell that using scrollable cursor with UI is a bad practice. It says

> Get in, grab your data, then get out. Later on, when the user decides
>   to scroll up or down (which will usually be eons of time later from
>   the point of view of your CPU), run another query to refresh the
>   screen with new data.

As far as I know, android cursors work exactly this way. Android's [`SQLiteCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) (that is actually used with [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) class) is a subclass of the [`AbstractWindowedCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractWindowedCursor.html). `AbstractWindowedCursor` uses [`CursorWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html) within it, that is, as per documentation:

> A buffer containing multiple cursor rows.

Each time the limit of this buffer is reached, `AbstractWindowedCursor` makes new `CursorWindow` and fills it with data.

**P.S.** In fact, these windows keep fairly big amount of data. It,s not limited by the screen size and far more than 5 or 50 rows (to be precise, it can be limited by 5 or even 1 row, if your rows contain, say, a thousand columns), and we as developers rarely face such behaviour.

Comment: I reviewed the Android code again, yes, after filling the CursorWindow, it use `sqlite3_reset` to release the query. But doesn't this makes the result of the query inconsistent?? For example if database changed, `getCount` can return different size?

Comment: Also in case the CursorWindow is not big enough, doesn't this means it will query in UI thread?? Anyway it seems to be a big hack to me

Comment: @molikto, i'm not quite sure if it query exactly in UI thread, but it definitely affect it, so filling new `CursorWindow` can cause noticable lag during, say, scrolling or fast-scrolling a `ListView`. Your assumption about incosistency also makes sense. E.g. if you create a trigger for a table, that cause change in another table, it might not be covered by built-in observation mechanism of Cursors, so you will need either to implement your own observation mechanism or force all dependent cursor to be refreshed.

Comment: About the inconsistency, I think it is not only the triggers, a direct modification using delete can cause the result of a cursor inconsistent (for example a cursor has cached the count after `getCount` is called first time, and then one record is deleted, then try to fill the window, it will not be full?). At least that's what I think, but I didn't experiment it yet....

Comment: Most things you do through framework classes work well (Content Providers, SQLiteCursor). Problems come when you get round the framework solutions by any way, e.g. direct changing the sqlite, native C code, etc...

Comment: @molikto, I highlighted the triggers, because they were fairly common mistake for me - it's likely to cause inconsistence unintentionally with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142985/discussion-between-aleksandr-medvedev-and-molikto).